# Flexible layout. How to show conditional content without CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm building the tablet version of a site through css max-width media queries. Adapting styles have been easy so far.
But I found for one part of the site I need to show divs with 2 images instead of 3 and I can't find a way to do that with css.

Example:

Site version

```
<div>
  <div>Image1</div>
  <div>Image2</div>
  <div>Image3</div>
</div>
```

Tablet version (if max-width is whatever, show only two divs)

```
<div>
  <div>Image1</div>
  <div>Image2</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT

Ok, I'll try to be more specific since every answer has been related to display:none and though that's a great solution, it wouldn't work for what I'm trying to do.

The divs are part of a slideshow. In the full site version the slider shows groups of three images. So in the tablet version, the third image would now be part of the second group (but not disappear):

```
<div>
 <div>Image1</div>
 <div>Image2</div>
</div>

<div>
 <div>Image3</div>
 <div>Image4</div>
</div>
```

And so on...

I'm not sure if this can be done through css or if the problem needs to be addressed with some kind of in-html script. That's why I asked for a solution without css.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be good... The .hideme class of course can be placed inside a specific media query, and obviously can be renamed.

**CSS**

```
.hideme { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div>Image1</div>
  <div>Image2</div>
  <div class="hideme">Image3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will only ever be 3 divs there and you always want to hide the 3rd one, you could do it like this:

```
div:nth-child(3) {
    display:none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6JhK/)

Comment: nth-child() could be a problem only if you need the compatibility with IE<=8. Otherwise this is cool!

Comment: This is supposed to be for a tablet, so IE<=8 isn't an issue (desktop IE8 ignores it I think)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to specify in the media-query the div that you want to "hide".

Something like:

```
<div>
  <div>Image1</div>
  <div>Image2</div>
  <div class="ThingTohide">Image3</div>
</div>

@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:480px) {
    .ThingTohide {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid of me, but why does your title say "without CSS" when you're searching for a solution in CSS?

Aside of that, does your tablet version actually have only 2 divs coming from the backend, or is it the way it is supposed to be rendered?

In the second case you can just use `display: none` on the third div.

```css
div > div:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Image1</div>
  <div>Image2</div>
  <div>Image3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited the question. Can't do that since I need the image to still be there, but in the next group. This solution would just make disappear images 3,6,9... in the tablet version.

Comment: Oh boy :) usually I'd say don't wrap the images inside div's, and just use the auto-break when the next image wouldn't fit, but since you are using a slider I don't know if this is possible...

Comment: Yeah... that's the problem. It's a purchased slider. And it detects what you want to show through divs containing the image with a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery

```
<div>
 <div>Image1</div>
 <div>Image2</div>
 <div class="move">Image3</div>
</div>

<div class="group2">
 <div>Image4</div>
</div>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width()<640) { //to check if it's on mobile device, or any other method if it's not suits you
        $('.move').prependTo('.group2');
    };
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie to jquery. Where should I paste the conditional code?

Comment: basically wherever in your page, but to be safe, put that at the bottom of your page. don't forget to put it in <script></script> tag and also include jquery in your page.

Comment: did you already resize yor browser to 640px and try to reload it? if that's not working too, try my edited answer

Comment: If you resize the window in real time it just doesn't work. If you reload with the window being tablet size, it shows 2 images in the first group, but the third image isn't in the second group and the styling is a mess for some reason.

Comment: btw, you can check the original unchaged test site in cerealex.com/demo if it is of any help to figure things out.